# How do I create a WebRazorHostFactory that does not mess up intellisense?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, intellisense

If I create a new WebRazorHostFactory like this:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class TestMvcWebRazorHostFactory : WebRazorHostFactory
    {
        public override WebPageRazorHost CreateHost(string virtualPath, string physicalPath)
        {
            WebPageRazorHost host = base.CreateHost(virtualPath, physicalPath);

            if (!host.IsSpecialPage)
            {
                return new MvcWebPageRazorHost(virtualPath, physicalPath);
            }

            return host;
        }
    }
}
```

and reference it in ~/Views/Web.config like this:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="Test.TestMvcWebRazorHostFactory" />
    ...
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

the intellisense in my view files no longer recognize the "model" and "TextBoxFor" in:

```
@model Test.Models.Person

<div>
    @this.Html.TextBoxFor( x => x.Name )
</div>
```

How do I make a new WebRazorHostFactory that doesn't mess up the intellisense in the view files?

In the MvcWebPageRazorHost I see they run a function "GetRidOfNamespace("System.Web.WebPages.Html");", but I'm not sure if this is the problem? I have tried to write a different class that does the same thing as MvcWebPageRazorHost without this function and it seems to have no effect. Thanks.

Comment: The GetRidOfNamespace method should not be causing this problem, it removes the namespaces provided by ASP.Net Web Pages because they conflict with ASP.Net MVC. The MvcWebPageRazorHost then goes on to **add** the MVC-related namespaces. As for what _is_ going on, I'm not 100% sure. Can you explain why you're changing the Host? IntelliSense should be picking up on a custom host registered through web.config, but it was _primarily_ designed for MVC, so it's possible there are glitches.

Comment: I was looking in to writing a custom WebPageRazorHost that removes spaces between most tags (e.g. removing the space between:
<input /> <input /> because they are on different lines). I had this functioning as intended, however intellisense did not work with this, so I just used the most basic example that I have given above (providing the default MvcWebPageRazorHost), which also does not work well with intellisense.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by changing it at runtime in my Application_Start in Global.asax.cs.

Here's the code:

```
        var hostSection = WebConfigurationManager.GetSection(HostSection.SectionName, "/Views") as HostSection;

        if (hostSection != null)
        {
            hostSection.FactoryType = "Type.Name, Assembly";
        }
```

This would need to be done for any areas you might have as well.

Comment: I had to use "~/Views" as the path (note the tilde), since my app can run in a virtual paths.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the assembly that contains the custom factory into the GAC so Visual Studio can use it.